# How To Grant A Specific Login Under Acitve Directory Group To View Server State In SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2017

I want to grant only a login who is under an active directory user group to view server state in sql server. How can i do it?

Comment: You add the group as a login and assign permissions to the login.

Comment: Yeah. There is a AD login in my sql server. And, there are several people under that AD group. I manage the privileges only over AD groups and now, i just want to grant only a specific person under an AD group to view the server state. I want to try to learn if this is possible or not for just a specific person. @DavidBrowne-Microsoft

Comment: That person would need an individual login.

Comment: As David mentioned, you would need to add a **Login** in your SQL Server for the individual person's AD account, and then you can assign permissions on that **Login** just the same as if you were doing it to a **Login** for an AD Group. Keep in mind the permissions are cumulative, but *deny first*. So if the **Login** of the AD Group has permissions to read from a specific database then the **Login** of an AD account in that AD Group will also be able to implicitly read from that same database without you having to provide that permission to that **Login**. Conversely if you explicitly...

Comment: ...denied the **Login** of the AD Group from reading from a database but granted that permission to the **Login** of an AD account, that AD account would still be implicitly denied from reading from that database.